# Class C network, calculating next subnet range.

Tags: networking, routes, ip, subnet, cidr

This is a very simple question with a very simple answer, I apologize for asking it however as I found the answer isn't readily available and this may help somebody else.

I have a class C address 193.50.0.1 and am using the mask 28 to split it into 16 subnets with 14 hosts.

I understand that my first address would be:

```
Network       195.50.0.0/28
Netmask       255.255.255.240
Broadcast     195.50.0.15
Host range    195.50.0.1 – 195.50.0.14
```

But I am confused where the boundaries of the next subnet start, would be simple a matter of incrementing the start and ending positions for the next 15 subnets? for example would the next network be:

```
Network       195.50.0.16/28
Netmask       255.255.255.240
Broadcast     195.50.0.27
Host range    195.50.0.17 – 195.50.0.26
```

If not, how do I calculate the next subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
Network       195.50.0.16/28
Netmask       255.255.255.240
Broadcast     195.50.0.31
Host range    195.50.0.16 – 195.50.0.31
```

You can get host range by **separating IP to NET_ID and HOST_ID**

```
NET ID =  (28bits) 11000011.00110010.00000000.0001 
HOST ID = (4bits)  0000 ~ 1111

So the host range is :
11000011.00110010.00000000.00010000    195.50.0.16
11000011.00110010.00000000.00011111    195.50.0.31
```

You can use '**AND**' operation to get Broadcast

```
195.50.0.16                    11000011.00110010.00000000.00010000 
(HOST_ID are '1')              00000000.00000000.00000000.00001111
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Broadcast                      11000011.00110010.00000000.00011111 = 195.50.0.31
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to say a yes would have sufficed but this will hopefully help someone else. Thank you.